# How to push both value and key into PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Take a look at this code:

```
$GET = array();    
$key = 'one=1';
$rule = explode('=', $key);
/* array_push($GET, $rule[0] => $rule[1]); */
```

I'm looking for something like this so that:

```
print_r($GET);
/* output: $GET[one => 1, two => 2, ...] */
```

Is there a function to do this? (because `array_push` won't work this way)

Answer (score 971, accepted):

Nope, there is no `array_push()` equivalent for associative arrays because there is no way determine the next key.

You'll have to use

```
$arrayname[indexname] = $value;
```

Comment: How to add multiple keys and values to an array? for example I have [indexname1] = $value1 and [indexname2] = $value2, and I want to add them to $arrayname

Comment: @KingGoeks `$arrayname = array('indexname1' => $value1, 'indexname2' => $value2);` would set them as the only items in `$arrayname`. If you already have `$arrayname` set and want to keep its values, try `$arrayname += $anotherarray`. Keep in mind any existing keys in the first array would be overwritten by the second.

Comment: "Keep in mind any existing keys in the first array would be overwritten by the second" that is not true, the first array has priority. if you do `$a = array("name" => "John"); $a += array("name" => "Tom");`then `$a["name"]` will be "John"

Comment: it is the faster of the two: array_push vs array[]. Array[] is about 2x as fast if i remember correctly...

Comment: this is very fine and possibly the best for named-key arrays; only ensure that the key-name (the named index) does not clash with an already existing one. also ensure that the parent array exists first before you start 'pushing' your items into it.

Comment: Warning: `$a['123'] = 456;` - string '123' is converted to integer key 123.

Comment: I have been coding professionally in php for more than 2 years..... I am ashamed that I actually had to look for this and didnt immediately click in my brain.

Answer (score 104):

**Pushing** a value into an array automatically creates a numeric key for it.

When adding a key-value pair to an array, you already have the key, you don't need one to be created for you. Pushing a key into an array doesn't make sense. You can only set the value of the specific key in the array.

```
// no key
array_push($array, $value);
// same as:
$array[] = $value;

// key already known
$array[$key] = $value;
```

Answer (score 89):

You can use the union operator (`+`) to combine arrays and keep the keys of the added array. For example:

```
<?php

$arr1 = array('foo' => 'bar');
$arr2 = array('baz' => 'bof');
$arr3 = $arr1 + $arr2;

print_r($arr3);

// prints:
// array(
//   'foo' => 'bar',
//   'baz' => 'bof',
// );
```

So you could do `$_GET += array('one' => 1);`.

There's more info on the usage of the union operator vs `array_merge` in the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php.

Comment: The basic difference between `array_merge()` and `+` operator is when the 2 arrays contain values on the same key `+` operator ignores the value from second array (does not override), also it does not renumber/reindex the numeric keys...

Answer (score 68):

I wonder why the simplest method hasn't been posted yet:

```
$arr = ['company' => 'Apple', 'product' => 'iPhone'];
$arr += ['version' => 8];
```

Comment: it is not exactly the same, in array_merge, the array on the right wins on key conflict, in " += " the array on the left wins

Comment: @santiagoarizti What do you mean by "wins"?

Comment: if two arrays have both the same key, `array_merge` and *array union* (`+=`) behave in the opposite way i.e. array_merge will respect the value from the second array and array union will respect the value from the first array.

Comment: Legend!! Just  `$arr += [$key => $value];` did it perfectly fine for me, thanks!

Answer (score 26):

I would like to add my answer to the table and here it is :

```
//connect to db ...etc
$result_product = /*your mysql query here*/ 
$array_product = array(); 
$i = 0;

foreach ($result_product as $row_product)
{
    $array_product [$i]["id"]= $row_product->id;
    $array_product [$i]["name"]= $row_product->name;
    $i++;
}

//you can encode the array to json if you want to send it to an ajax call
$json_product =  json_encode($array_product);
echo($json_product);
```

hope that this will help somebody

Answer (score 22):

Exactly what Pekka said...

Alternatively, you can probably use array_merge like this if you wanted:

```
array_merge($_GET, array($rule[0] => $rule[1]));
```

But I'd prefer Pekka's method probably as it is much simpler.

Answer (score 13):

#### 2023

A lot of answers. Some helpful, others good but awkward. Since you don't need complicated and expensive arithmetic operations, loops etc. for a simple operation like adding an element to an array, here is my collection of **One-Liner-Add-To-Array-Functions**.

```php
$array = ['a' => 123, 'b' => 456]; // init Array

$array['c'] = 789; // 1.
$array += ['d' => '012']; // 2.
$array = array_merge($array, ['e' => 345]); // 3.
$array = [...$array, 'f' => 678]; // 4.

print_r($array);
// Output:
/* 
Array
(
    [a] => 123
    [b] => 456
    [c] => 789
    [d] => 012
    [e] => 345
    [f] => 678
)
*/
```

In 99,99% i use **version 1**. (`$array['c'] = 789;`). But i like **version 4**. That is the version with the splat operator (https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php).

Comment: Please start your counting from 0. We arent barbarians.

Answer (score 9):

I was just looking for the same thing and I realized that, once again, my thinking is different because I am old school. I go all the way back to BASIC and PERL and sometimes I forget how easy things really are in PHP.

I just made this function to take all settings from the database where their are 3 columns. setkey, item (key) & value (value) and place them into an array called settings using the same key/value without using push just like above.

Pretty easy & simple really

```
// Get All Settings
$settings=getGlobalSettings();


// Apply User Theme Choice
$theme_choice = $settings['theme'];

.. etc etc etc ....




function getGlobalSettings(){

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(wds_db_host, wds_db_user, wds_db_pass) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db($dbc, wds_db_name) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error());
    $MySQL = "SELECT * FROM systemSettings";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $MySQL);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
        $settings[$row['item']] = $row['value'];   // NO NEED FOR PUSH
        }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
return $settings;
}
```

So like the other posts explain... In php there is no need to "PUSH" an array when you are using

Key => Value

AND... There is no need to define the array first either.

$array=array();

Don't need to define or push. Just assign $array[$key] = $value; It is automatically a push and a declaration at the same time.

I must add that for security reasons, (P)oor (H)elpless (P)rotection, I means Programming for Dummies, I mean PHP.... hehehe I suggest that you only use this concept for what I intended. Any other method could be a security risk. There, made my disclaimer!

Answer (score 9):

A bit late but if you don't mind a nested array you could take this approach:

```
$main_array = array(); //Your array that you want to push the value into
$value = 10; //The value you want to push into $main_array
array_push($main_array, array('Key' => $value));
```

To clarify,
if you output `json_encode($main_array)` that will look like `[{"Key":"10"}]`

Answer (score 8):

This is the solution that may useful for u

```
Class Form {
# Declare the input as property
private $Input = [];

# Then push the array to it
public function addTextField($class,$id){
    $this->Input ['type'][] = 'text';
    $this->Input ['class'][] = $class;
    $this->Input ['id'][] = $id;
}

}

$form = new Form();
$form->addTextField('myclass1','myid1');
$form->addTextField('myclass2','myid2');
$form->addTextField('myclass3','myid3');
```

## When you dump it. The result like this

```
array (size=3)
  'type' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'text' (length=4)
      1 => string 'text' (length=4)
      2 => string 'text' (length=4)
  'class' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'myclass1' (length=8)
      1 => string 'myclass2' (length=8)
      2 => string 'myclass3' (length=8)
  'id' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'myid1' (length=5)
      1 => string 'myid2' (length=5)
      2 => string 'myid3' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 4):

A bit weird, but this worked for me

```
    $array1 = array("Post Slider", "Post Slider Wide", "Post Slider");
    $array2 = array("Tools Sliders", "Tools Sliders", "modules-test");
    $array3 = array();

    $count = count($array1);

    for($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++){
       $array3[$array1[$x].$x] = $array2[$x];
    }

    foreach($array3 as $key => $value){
        $output_key = substr($key, 0, -1);
        $output_value = $value;
        echo $output_key.": ".$output_value."<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a simple function:

```
function push(&$arr,$new) {
    $arr = array_merge($arr,$new);
}
```

so that I can "upsert" new element easily:

```
push($my_array, ['a'=>1,'b'=>2])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 $arr = array("key1"=>"value1", "key2"=>"value");
    print_r($arr);
```

// prints array['key1'=>"value1", 'key2'=>"value2"]

Answer (score 3):

The simple way:

```
$GET = array();    
$key = 'one=1';
parse_str($key, $GET);
```

http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 3):

Example array_merge()....

`$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);`

Array([color] => green,[0] => 2,[1] => 4,[2] => a,[3] => b,[shape] => trapezoid,[4] => 4,)

Answer (score 2):

```
array_push($arr, ['key1' => $value1, 'key2' => value2]);
```

This works just fine.
creates the the key with its value in the array

Comment: Downvoted. This just pushes a new array at the end of the existing `$arr` array.

Answer (score 2):

hi i had same problem i find this solution you should use two arrays then combine them both

```
 <?php

$fname=array("Peter","Ben","Joe");

$age=array("35","37","43");

$c=array_combine($fname,$age);

print_r($c);

?>
```

reference : [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_combine.asp)

Answer (score 2):

For add to first position with `key` and `value`

```
$newAarray = [newIndexname => newIndexValue] ;

$yourArray = $newAarray + $yourArray ;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some great example already given here. Just adding a simple example to push associative array elements to root numeric index index.

```
$intial_content = array();

if (true) {
 $intial_content[] = array('name' => 'xyz', 'content' => 'other content');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
array_push($GET, $GET['one']=1);
```

It works for me.

Comment: This executes `$GET['one']=1`, then uses the return value of that statement (=1, the rvalue), and then executes `array_push($GET, 1)`. Result = [0]->1, [one]->1

Answer (score -3):

I usually do this:

```
$array_name = array(
'key1' => 'value1',
'key2' => 'value2',
'key3' => 'value3'
);
```

Comment: This is not an array push though it does not help the question. Here check this and fix your answer.

Comment: array_push ( $array , $values )

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php