# Find element in multidimensional array and add something after it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array

```
[0] {
    [0] {
        [0]: 'Element 1'
        [1]: 'Element 2'
        [2]: 'Element 3'
        [3]: 'Element 4'
    }
    [1] {
        [0]: 'Element 5'
        [1]: 'Element 6'
        [2]: 'Element 7'
        [3]: 'Element 8'
    }
    [2] {
        [0]: 'Element 9'
        [1]: 'Element 10'
        [2]: 'Element 11'
        [3]: 'Element 12'
    }
}
```

Now, i want to add an element between the elements 6 & 7. Currently, i'm using this

```
$.map($myArray, function(i, e) {
    if (i.indexOf('Element 6') >= 0) {
        $myArray.splice($.inArray('Element 6', $myArray[e]) + 1, 0, 'Element X');
    }
});
```

However, i'm pretty sure, that this is a suboptimal solution and that there's an easier (and more efficient) way to achieve this.

Maybe, i'm just thinking too complicated.

Comment: any how you are passing indexes to add element in between see this link might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308252/php-add-elements-to-multidimensional-array-with-array-push any how you need to modify slite to insert into specified location.

Comment: Seeing that mix of jQuery (`inArray`) and native methods (`indexOf`) hurts my eyes…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more or less the good way, you can't avoid looping.

There is place for a few optimizations though :

- don't use `$.map` but a standard `for` loop. `$.map` is pretty but calls a function at each step
- use `break` to stop iterating when you find your item
- don't search twice the position of the item
- don't use `$.inArray` (especially as you used `indexOf` before)

Here's a better code :

```
for (var i=0; i<$myArray.length; i++) {
    var index = $myArray[i].indexOf('Element 6');
    if (~index) {
        $myArray[i].splice(index+1, 0, 'Element X');
        break;
    }
}
```

[Simple performance comparison](http://jsperf.com/searchandinsert) (note that the performance gain will depend on the data)

More generally, when you don't need compatibility with very old (and almost forgotten) browsers, and I assume you don't need that compatibility as you use `indexOf`, you should avoid using compatibility functions like `$.map` or `$.inArray` as they mostly add an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

should be as simple as `myArray[0][1].splice(2, 0, 'Element X)`

assuming that `myArray` is the top level array

Comment: The problem is, that the position of the element may vary.