# How to insert new Elements into a multidimensional array without push_array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

As I want to plot some temperature graphs with the Google Chart Library I am building an Array in PHP to encode it to JSON as described in

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods

The first entry of "dataTable['cols']" is the x-axis. I then want to add some more lines one by one.

This works:

```
$dataTable = array();
$dataTable['cols'] = array(
    array('id' => 'time_axis', 'label' => 'Time', 'type' => 'datetime')
);
foreach($sensors as $id => $description) {
//Entries in $sensors are from a database
    $column = array('id' => $id, 'label' => $description, 'type' => 'number');
    array_push($dataTable['cols'],$column);
}
```

This does not (500 Server Error):

```
$dataTable = array();
$dataTable['cols'] = array(
    array('id' => 'time_axis', 'label' => 'Time', 'type' => 'datetime')
);
foreach($sensors as $id => $description) {
//Entries in $sensors are from a database
    $column = array('id' => $id, 'label' => $description, 'type' => 'number');
    $dataTable['cols'][] = $column;
}
```

When I'm reading the accepted answer here

[PHP add elements to multidimensional array with array_push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308252/php-add-elements-to-multidimensional-array-with-array-push)

right, it should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to add your x-axis with the same way :

`$dataTable['cols'][] = array('id' => 'time_axis', 'label' => 'Time', 'type' => 'datetime');`

And don't forget the `$` in front of `dataTable` !

Comment: Yeah thanks, that works now. Can you explain why this makes a difference ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it's because PHP create a 'static' array with the first syntax and allocate the right amount of memory for his content. So, when you want to add something inside, you have to tell it via `array_push()` because PHP need to re-allocate memory. I guess the other syntax just open a sort of buffer whitch you can put what you want on the fly. Maybe these memory trick are explained in the doc. Hope this help !

Comment: Take a look at the linked list : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list 
Maybe the second syntax use them and explain your question !

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($items as $index => $array)
{ 
 $items[$index]['id']=$id; 
}
```

Try this.