# how to push values in multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, php-7

`$classType` array i am storing the class wise type like class 1 having type A & class 2 having type is A & class 3 having type is B

`$clollege['studentDetails']` array i want to push type from `$classType` array based on class what is the type

`$clollege['studentDetails']` grade and `$classType` class both are same.

> Expected Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [grade] => 2
            [hobbies] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A
                    [1] => B
                )
        [type] => A

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [grade] => 2
            [hobbies] => Array
                (
                    [0] => A
                )
           [type] => A

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [grade] => 3
            [hobbies] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C
                )
        [type] => A

        )
```

I have tried but not working my expected answer,kindly anyone updaye my answer, i have posted my code in below section. i know this is simple question , if anyone post your so that i can learn from here
How to push

> My Code

```
<?php
$classType = [
    ["class" => "1", "type" => "A"],
    ["class" => "2", "type" => "A"],
    ["class" => "3", "type" => "B"]
];

$clollege['studentDetails'] = [
   ["grade" => "2", "hobbies" => ["A" , "B"] ],
   ["grade" => "2", "hobbies" => ["A" ] ],
   ["grade" => "3", "hobbies" => [ "C" ] ]
];

foreach ($classType as $item) {
        $clollege['studentDetails'][$item['class']]['type'] = $item['type'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($clollege['studentDetails']);exit;
?>
```

> Update code section

```
$studentList['studentDetails'] = [
    [ "group" => ["id" => 1 , "grade" => "2"] ],
    [ "group" => ["id" => 2 , "grade" => "2", ] ],
    [ "group" => [ "id" => 3, "grade" => "3"] ]
];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP add elements to multidimensional array with array\_push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308252/php-add-elements-to-multidimensional-array-with-array-push)

Comment: What is class, and how does that realate to the expected output? Is it always index 0 that you mix with index 0, and so on?

Comment: `grade` you can not use same key name in an array

Comment: Can you please anyone post your answer?, i tried but i couldn't get my expected answer

Comment: why are you expecting to have two same key `grade`?

Comment: Ohh!, sorry that is not `grade`, i need to push `type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way with the help of [**array_walk()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

```
$classType = [
    ["class" => "1", "type" => "A"],
    ["class" => "2", "type" => "A"],
    ["class" => "3", "type" => "B"]
];

$clollege['studentDetails'] = [
    ["grade" => "2", "hobbies" => ["A" , "B"] ],
    ["grade" => "2", "hobbies" => ["A" ] ],
    ["grade" => "3", "hobbies" => [ "C" ] ]
];

$classType = array_column($classType, 'type', "class");
array_walk($clollege['studentDetails'], function(&$item) use($classType) {
    $item['type'] = $classType[$item['grade']];
});

echo '<pre>';
print_r($clollege['studentDetails']);
echo '</pre>';
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/BHS4A).

Comment: Its for `echo`. Updated, you can try it now.

Comment: One small question suppose `$studentList['studentDetails']` array **grade** it is under group array means, how to change your code,expected output is same.

Comment: **I have posted my $studentList['studentDetails'] in update code section**

Comment: @KaniR, I'm not clear about your question. What are the new data structures? is it `$clollege['studentDetails']` or `$studentList['studentDetails']`? Very confusing. Clearly describe what are the two data structure.

Comment: I got answer now

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `grade` as key 2 times in a single or sub array element, i have mentioned solution by using `type` index.

You can use `foreach` with `array_reduce`

```
 foreach($clollege['studentDetails'] as $key => &$val){
    $grade       = $val['grade'];
    $val['type'] = array_reduce($classType, function($r, $item) use ($grade){
      return ($item['class'] == $grade) ? $item['type'] : $r;
    }); 
  }
  print_r($clollege);
```

Updates

Change code

```
$grade = $val['grade'];
```

to

```
$grade = $val['group']['grade'];
```

If there is chance for the both of the situation use

```
$grade  = isset($val['group']['grade']) ? $val['group']['grade'] : $val['grade'];
```

Working DEMO : https://3v4l.org/5HGLk

Comment: One small question suppose `$studentList['studentDetails']` array **grade** it is under group array means, how to change your code,expected output is same.

Comment: **I have posted my $studentList['studentDetails'] in update code section**