# Pushing values into multidimensional array

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm already getting below array results as follows. All I wanted is to add more entries in it.
How do I do that?

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [number] => AAA1222
                    [short_description] => User unable to print
                    [state] => Closed
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [number] => AAA1223
                    [short_description] => Share drive not accessible
                    [state] => Closed
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [number] => AAA1224
                    [short_description] => Network is down
                    [state] => Closed
                )

        )
)
```

If I wanted to add more entries to the array like

```
[number] => AAA1225
[short_description] => Cable replacement on workstation 12
[state] => Closed
```

How do I accomplish that.

Thanks!!

Comment: Use array_push() method of php.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP add elements to multidimensional array with array\_push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308252/php-add-elements-to-multidimensional-array-with-array-push)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you are storing above array in a variable named as `$arr`.

```
$arr = [ ... ]; // contains your existing data.

// To add new data
$arrNewData = [
    'number' => 'AAA1225',
    'short_description' => 'Cable replacement on workstation 12',
    'state' => 'Closed' 
];

// Push data to existing array.
$arr['result'][] = $arrNewData;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with array_push() function too.

Your existence array:

```
$myArr['result'] = [........]
```

New array values

```
$data['number'] = 'AAA1224';
$data['short_description'] = 'Network is down';
$data['state'] = 'Closed';
```

Push new array into existance array:

```
array_push($myArr['result'],$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another array data to your existing array

Keep your existing data into a variable $data.

```
$data = [ ... ]; // here you have result index and array data
```

Then add new result item as an array.

```
$data['result'][] = [
    'number' => 'AAA1225',
    'short_description' => 'Cable replacement on workstation 12',
    'state' => 'Closed'
];
```