# php - push array into an array -(pushing both key and the array)

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I am trying to add an array to an existing array. I am able to add the array using the  **array_push** . The only problem is that when trying to add array that contains an array keys, it adds an extra array within the existing array.

It might be best if I show to you

```
foreach ($fields as $f)
{  
    if ($f == 'Thumbnail')
    {
        $thumnail = array('Thumbnail' => Assets::getProductThumbnail($row['id'] );
        array_push($newrow, $thumnail);
    }
    else
    { 
        $newrow[$f] = $row[$f];
    }
}
```

The **fields** array above is part of an array that has been dynamically fed from an SQl query it is then fed into a new array called `$newrow`. However, to this `$newrow` array, I need to add the thumbnail array fields .

Below is the output ( using `var_dump`) from the above code. The only problem with the code is that I don't want to create a seperate array within the arrays. I just need it to be added to the array.

```
 array(4) { ["Product ID"]=> string(7) "1007520"
           ["SKU"]=> string(5) "G1505"
           ["Name"]=> string(22) "150mm Oval Scale Ruler"            
           array(1) { ["Thumbnail"]=> string(77) "thumbnails/products/5036228.jpg" } }
```

I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to push both value and key into array with php](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2926547/476)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really want is:

```
$newrow['Thumbnail'] = Assets::getProductThumbnail($row['id']);
```

Comment: thank you everyone for your kind help. i guess i was a little confused about how the arrays work. the solution provided by deceze and xdim222 was correct. thank you everyone for your kind help

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function

```
$newrow = array_merge($newrow, $thumnail);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also assign it directly to $newrow:

```
if ($f == 'Thumbnail')
  $newrow[$f] = Assets::getProductThumbnail($row['id']);
else
...
```

Or if you want your code to be shorter:

```
foreach($fields as $f)
  $newrow[$f] = ($f == 'Thumbnail')? Assets::getProductThumbnail($row['id']) : $row[$f];
```

But if you're getting paid by number of lines in your code, don't do this, stay on your code :) j/k

Comment: hi everyone. array_merge only works from php 5.4; i am required to use php  5.3. I also cannot use the solution posted by xdim222 because i need to place the array 'key and value' within the new $newrow array. Does anyone have any advice

Comment: @andreea115 array_merge is from PHP 4. However, there is a difference in the function signature between versions 4 and 5. Since PHP version 5 the array_merge accepts only arrays. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php#refsect1-function.array-merge-changelog.