# How to push multiple key and value into php array?

Tags: php, arrays

I've searched how to push both key and value and I found this : [How to push both value and key into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121548/how-to-push-both-value-and-key-into-array-with-php)

But my question is how to add more than one key and value into an array?

`$somearray` :

```
Array ( 
[id] => 1645819602 
[name] => Michael George)
```

I want to add this into `$somearray` :

```
[first_name] => Michael 
[last_name] => George
[work] => Google
```

So the output will be

```
Array ( 
    [id] => 1645819602 
    [name] => Michael George
    [first_name] => Michael 
    [last_name] => George
    [work] => Google)
```

I know this code will not work

```
$arrayname[first_name] = Michael;
$arrayname[last_name] = George;
$arrayname[work] = Google;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: you have syntax error in your PHP code. Error messages should have already told you so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to enclose the array key in quotes and also the value if its a string.If the value is an integer then there is no need of enclosing the value in quotes.But you must enclose the value in quotes if its a string.So you need to change he code like this

```
$arrayname['first_name'] = 'Michael';
$arrayname['last_name'] = 'George';
$arrayname['work'] = 'Google';
```

Answer (score 6):

This is how I add all the elements from one array to another:

```php
<?php
$oneArray = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
$anotherArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array_push($anotherArray, ...$oneArray);
//['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the idea:

```
<?

$array = array(
         [id] => 1);

$array["hello"] = "world";

print_r($array); //prints Array (
                             [id] => 1,
                             [hello] => "world")


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for adding value into array,

```
$ArrayName['IndexName'] = $elementValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Here you need to add quotes to wrap index.

<?php
$arrayname['first_name'] = 'Michael';
$arrayname['last_name'] = 'George';
$arrayname['work'] = 'Google';
?>

Always use this when assigning any value in the array.
```

- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to put the `quote` when you assigning the value.

```
$arrayname[first_name] = 'Michael';
$arrayname[last_name] = 'George';
$arrayname[work] = 'Google';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ac_re_arr['date']      = array();
$ac_re_arr['amt']       = array();

$sql5   = mysql_query(" SELECT `id`,`bank_dues_amt`,`bank_dues` FROM `tbl_act` where `bank_dues_amt` !='' and `case_id`='$case_id' ")or die(mysql_error());
while($data5    = mysql_fetch_array($sql5))
{
    $amt3       = explode('$',$data5['bank_dues_amt']);
    $date3      = explode('$',$data5['bank_dues']);
    $k          = 0;
    foreach($amt3 as $key3)
    {
        array_push($ac_re_arr['date'],$date3[$k]);
        array_push($ac_re_arr['amt'],$amt3[$k]);
        $k++;
    }
}
print_r($ac_re_arr);
```

**Output like this**

```
Array (
  [date] => Array (
    [0] => 10-08-2017
    [1] => 15-07-2016
  )
  [amt] => Array (
    [0] => 5000
    [1] => 2000
  )
)
```