# How can I construct an array with a specific key using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of 4 elements `$device_report = [];` with these data in it

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "up_bytes" => 2818
    "down_bytes" => 948
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "up_bytes" => 472
    "down_bytes" => 439
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "up_bytes" => 3364
    "down_bytes" => 1317
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "up_bytes" => 3102
    "down_bytes" => 1682
  ]
]
```

---

**Right now, I have this**

```
    $device_report = [];
    foreach ($devices as $device){
        $device_mac = $device->device_mac; //080027E2FC7D
        $data = VSE::device($device_mac);
        array_push($device_report,$data);
    }
```

---

**I've tried**

```
    $device_report = [];
    foreach ($devices as $device){
        $device_mac = $device->device_mac; //080027E2FC7D
        $data = VSE::device($device_mac);
        array_push($device_report[$device_mac],$data);
    }
```

It give me error :

`array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given`

---

I just want to my key to be a specific device Mac Address rather than 0,1,2,3.

Any hints will be much appreciated !

Comment: Just do: `$device_report[$device_mac] = $data;`

Comment: Short and elegant. Thanks.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2121548/3933332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldnt use array_push for this. No reason to.

```
$device_report = [];
foreach ($devices as $device){
    $device_mac = $device->device_mac; //080027E2FC7D
    $data = VSE::device($device_mac);
    $device_report[$device_mac]=$data; // <-- This line changed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Per the documentation, [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

> `int array_push ( array &$array , mixed $value1 [, mixed $... ] )`
>
> `array_push()` treats **array** as a stack, and pushes the passed variables onto the end of array. The length of array increases by the number of variables pushed. Has the same effect as:

In your particular case, you're trying to create a new key and assign the array, so you're getting the error that `$device_report[$device_mac]` is not an array. This is indeed correct since the key doesn't already exist.

To overcome this, assign the array directly as oppose to using `array_push`.

Try this:

```
$device_report[$device_mac] = $data;
```

instead of:

```
array_push($device_report[$device_mac], $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$device_report = [];
foreach ($devices as $device){
    $device_mac = $device->device_mac; //080027E2FC7D
    $data = VSE::device($device_mac);

    //add this to init the array.
    if (is_array($device_report[$device_mac]) === false) {
        $device_report[$device_mac] = [];
    }

    array_push($device_report[$device_mac],$data);
}
```

The error message appear because `$device_report[$device_mac]` is null. You have to initialize the value with an array. With the following code you initialize it with a empty array if no array is available:

```
//add this to init the array.
if (is_array($device_report[$device_mac]) === false) {
    $device_report[$device_mac] = [];
}
```