# PHP Arrays: How to add 'key & value' to an existing array

Tags: php, arrays, key-value, array-push

I do not know how to add a key and value to the existing array. My array goes like this. Initially I have tried adding using `array_push()` but it added not as I needed it.

I have given my output after I gave the 'var_dump'.

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
     'id' => int 7
      'title' => string 'Pongal' (length=6)
      'start' => string '2016-05-16' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
       'id' => int 8
      'title' => string 'big day' (length=7)
      'start' => string '2016-05-04' (length=10)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 9
      'title' => string 'marriage day' (length=12)
      'start' => string '2016-05-19' (length=10)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 10
      'title' => string 'Karthiks  bday' (length=14)
      'start' => string '2016-06-11' (length=10)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => int 12
     'title' => string 'Election date announced' (length=23)
      'start' => string '2016-06-01' (length=10)
```

Now, I'd like to insert array('sample_key' => 'sample_value') after all the  elements of each array.

How can I do it? This is I want the result to be like this:-

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => int 7
      'title' => string 'Pongal' (length=6)
      'start' => string '2016-05-16' (length=10)
      ‘color’ => ‘red’
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => int 8
      'title' => string 'big day' (length=7)
      'start' => string '2016-05-04' (length=10)
      ‘color’ => ‘red’
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => int 9
      'title' => string 'marriage day' (length=12)
      'start' => string '2016-05-19' (length=10)
      ‘color’ => ‘red’
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => int 10
      'title' => string 'Karthiks  bday' (length=14)
      'start' => string '2016-06-11' (length=10)
      ‘color’ => ‘red’
  4 => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => int 12
      'title' => string 'Election date announced' (length=23)
      'start' => string '2016-06-01' (length=10)
      ‘color’ => ‘red’
```

**Note that I have added 'color' => 'red' to all the indexes**

Comment: `$existingArray = []; $existingArray['mynewkey'] = 'mynewvalue';`?

Comment: using `foreach` and just do like: `$value[$key] = $new_val`

Comment: @Frayne, Can you show an example with the 'foreach'  pls..

Comment: yes check my answer.

Comment: what if the `key & value` would be dynamic?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121548/how-to-push-both-value-and-key-into-php-array

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just do this: [Working demo](https://3v4l.org/BT2cm)

using the `&` you can change the main array, and just use `$val['color'] = 'red'` to add a new key , value pair in the array.

```
foreach($arr as $key => &$val){
    $val['color'] = 'red';
}
```

Note that the 'write-back' feature of the ampersand persists even after the loop has finished: resetting `$val` to a new value will change the last element in `$val`, which is often unexpected. There are three ways around this class of bug:

- Avoid write-back and just use the full array expression to write values inside the loop;
- Don't re-use the `$val` variable in the same scope, even for another `foreach()` loop;
- Use `unset()` on the `$val` variable to disconnect it from the array it will write back to.

Comment: Just bear in mind with this that, after the loop, setting `$val` again will modify the last element in `$arr` - so watch out!

Comment: @halfer, So is there any ways to dismiss this?? I think `unset($val);`

Comment: Absolutely yes, that destroys the write-back link. I [wrote about this here](https://blog.jondh.me.uk/2011/05/seriously-fiendish-php-gotcha/).

Comment: isnt there a predefined php function for that? i was hoping for one

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach($arr as $key => $row){
  $arr[$key]['color']="red";
}
```

Comment: or you can use example from @frayne-konok, but you don't need `$key =>`,
just write `foreach ($arr as &$val)`

Comment: yeah peer that helped me, but can you explain me whats the purpose for '&$'?

Comment: I can try, but sorry for my english. 
When you use `foreach($array as $key=>$value)`, you have new variable $value everytime, which is **equal** to `$array[$key]`. But when you use `&$`, `$value` **not equal** to `$array[$key]`, it's **the same**