# Remove index from array, which has been created with array_push()

Tags: php

```
$colors = array();

for($i = 1; $i <=2; $i++) {
    if ($i == 1) {
        $current_colors = array('color1' => 'blue', 'color2' => 'red');
    }    
    else {
        $current_colors = array('color3' => 'yellow', 'color4' => 'green');
    }
    array_push($colors, $current_colors);
}

var_dump($colors);
```

This script returns:

> ```
> array(2) {
>   [0]=>
>   array(2) {
>     ["color1"]=>
>     string(4) "blue"
>     ["color2"]=>
>     string(3) "red"
>   }
>   [1]=>
>   array(2) {
>     ["color3"]=>
>     string(6) "yellow"
>     ["color4"]=>
>     string(5) "green"
>   }
> }
> ```

The array that I need shouldn't have any index (in this case `0` and `1`).

Instead of `array_push()` I also tried it with `array_merge()` but it returns an empty array.

How can I remove the index?

Comment: So what should your array look like? Are you wanting all four of the colours merged as one array? So that `$colours` has `color1`, `colour2` etc directly under it (without the `[0]` and `[1]`)?

Comment: @ObsidianAge yes, exactly!

Comment: You can't use `array_push` for this, as that will always create a numeric index. You'll want to access the array itself with square bracket notation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push both value and key into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121548/how-to-push-both-value-and-key-into-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
$colors = array_merge($colors, $current_colors);
```

`array_merge()` won't update `$colors`. You need to update it by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in PHP *always* have keys; albeit numeric ones if you don't specify them yourself. If you need to access the array as if it has no keys then you can use array_values().