# PHP Laravel MongoDb query: find document where an array object element contain a specific value

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I have a MongoDb collection where the documents have the following (simplified) structure:

```
{
    "_id": "<some-id>",
    "meta": {
        "keys": [
            {
                "key-A": "value-1"
            },
            {
                "key-B": "value-2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The "keys" value is an array that can have 0 or more elements, where each element is an object with a key and a value.

What I am trying to achieve is a PHP Laravel MongoDb query which can find document using just the value, which in the above example is either 'value-1' or 'value-2'. Please note that the element keys (e.g. "key-A" or "key-B" is unknown at run time.

I have tried many variations of probable solution but was not successful.

The nearest I got is when I am able to assume the the key is also available:

```
$documents = DB::connection('mongodb')
            ->table($collectionName)
            ->where('meta.keys', 'elemMatch', [$key => $value])
            ->get()
;
```

NB: PHP8.0, Laravel 9.52, MongoDb server 4.4, mongodb/laravel-mongodb 3.9.5

Comment: Have you tried building the query array dynamically? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75284818/2282634